# jar executed in a service not logging

Tags: java, sysvinit

I've wrapped a jar in a init.d service following the guide [here](http://www.jcgonzalez.com/linux-java-service-wrapper-example).

- created the service file under `/etc/init.d/`
- give proper permissions
- test the stop and start: `sudo service myservice start/stop/restart`;

The process is starting after the `sudo service myservice start` and I can see it from the command `ps -ef | grep -i myservice`
However the service should log its execution in a logging file in the same path of the jar, but this logging file is not created.

Instead, If the jar is executed through `java -jar myJar.jar &` and not within the service the log file is created.

How is it possible?

Thanks
Simone

Comment: Does the user account which is running the java program have read-write access to the log file?

Comment: That wrapper appears to be only for creating a pid/starting a java program, and you v talk nothing about what you are doing to generate logs. Have you also did the modification there

Comment: You are asking people to debug the arbitrary coded behaviour of a program that they do not know, with zero information about that program.  Answerers do not know all of the things that a program's built-in idiosyncratic logging system might be sensitive to.  That's not a particularly good van Smoorenburg `rc` script example to be following, either.

Comment: @EmmanuelRosa by the looks of the unit, root.

Comment: (And its supposed systemd update is an example of how _not_ to run Java services under systemd, incorporating at least two of the _House of Horror_ mistakes.)

Comment: @Emmanuel Rosa this is executed by root

Comment: @Rui F Ribeiro logs are generated by the jar execution. In its main process it's logging through log4j in a log file. I didn't change that part

Comment: @JdeBP I'm not asking to debug at all. i'm asking what and if I should change something in the service script executution. In the guide I put the link in the post I see the output redirections which I didn't understand completely. Maybe that's the issue

Comment: Yes, you are.  You are asking why the program is behaving differently, writing a file or not writing a file, in two different circumstances.  With zero information about the program, people cannot tell you.

Comment: @JdeBP again, I am asking not to debug anything. I asked if in case the jar is called by service it needs to be modified or not in order to have the same behavior as called by standard java jar execution

Comment: @SimoneCeccolini did you have any resolution? I also seem to hit similar issue today in my photon based linux box. I have a bash script which invokes java with `eval "java -jar all-vm-args my-app.jar"`, java process starts and seem to work normally, except that log files are not created. However if I run the java command directly, it generates log files. I run the script or java command as non-root user with sufficient permissions to logs directory. If it helps, my echo statements in the bash script are always getting written to script.log file in the same directory without any issues.

Comment: nevermind.. in my case the relative path configured for the log files in combination with `su -` in the script resulted in this issue! I was changing the the user in my script with `su - myuser`, it was changing the working directory to 'home' of myuser, and log files were getting created relative to the home directory itself.

Comment: @nevermind.. that was the issue, thanks!